# Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'error'

Tags: python, python-3.x, aws-lambda, elasticsearch-curator

I have a simple Python Code that uses Elasticsearch module "curator" to make snapshots.
I've tested my code locally and it works.

Now I want to run it in an AWS Lambda but I have this error :

> Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'error'

Here is how I proceeded :

I created manually a Lambda and gave it a "AISA-BasicLambdaExecutionRole" role. Then I created my package with my function and the dependencies that I installed with the command :

```
pip install elasticsearch-curator -t /<path>/myRepository
```

I zipped the content (not the folder) and uploaded it in my Lambda.
I changed the Handler name to "lambda_function.lambda_handler" (my function's name is "lambda_function.py").

Did I miss something ? This is my first time working with Lambda and Python

I've seen the other questions about this error :

> "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function'"

But nothing works for me.

**EDIT :**

Here is my lambda_function :

```
from __future__ import print_function
import curator
import time
from curator.exceptions import NoIndices
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

def lambda_handler(event, context):



  es = Elasticsearch()

  index_list = curator.IndexList(es)

  index_list.filter_by_regex(kind='prefix', value="logstash-")

  Number = 1

  try:
    while Number <= 3:

        Name="snapshotLmbd_n_"+ str(Number) +""

        curator.Snapshot(index_list, repository="s3-backup", name= Name , wait_for_completion=True).do_action()     
        Number += 1

        print('Just taking a nap ! will be back soon')
        time.sleep(30)

  except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('My bad ! I interrupted this')
        return
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Do you have `import error` of `from error import ...` in your `lambda_function.py` by any chance?

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo Thank you for your fast response. No I do not import error. I edited my post to add the function.

Comment: Check if your python script has executable permissions. chomd 755

Comment: @omuthu This was actually the problem ! Even though I set permissions to 755, after the upload to aws, apparently the permissions are lost. What I did actually is use serverless instead to avoid completely this problem. Can you write the answer so I can accept it ? 
Thank you again for the insight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, since you have everything else correct, check for the permissions of the python script.

It must have executable permissions (755)

Comment: Thank you. I would still recommend to use serverless to avoid all the trouble.

Comment: Actually, @AsmaaM, I just now had this problem WITH serverless hello-world-python template using Termux on a Chromebook, following steps on a Udemy tutorial, which likely didn't expect that platform. Template files had been created with 600 perms. Changing the template's handler.py to 755 fixed it for me. It was driving me absolutely crazy because it looked all the same as what was in a manually created window. This comment is partly to offer sincere thanks and partly to add some useful search keywords in case others get stuck similarly. :)